# Is there any way to enable/disable low power mode programmatically in iOS 9

Tags: ios9

The [only documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/LowPowerMode.html) refers to detecting it but nothing about enabling or disabling it.

Answer (score 3):

Low Power Mode is a system defined behavior. No public API is available to enable/disable it.
The user has to do it from iOS by himself.

Answer (score 0):

You would not expect applications to be allowed to enable/disable Low Power Mode.

There would always be some applications which wanted to disable it (brightening the screen), then Apple would get complaints about batteries running down.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking of making a quick button widget that sits in notifications to enable/disable it.